# Changing Supported Page Orientation programmatically for Windows 8.1 Phone

Tags: windows-store-apps, screen-orientation

My application supports both Portrait and Landscape orientations and automatically adapts UI to screen size. However I want to provide an option to lock the screen at current orientation.

If I just stop processing SizeChanged event, it doesn't help, since system still rotates the UI page, so it appears squeezed and truncated.

According to MSDN there is a way to set up supported orientations programmatically in Xna and Silverlight or Windows API (which is disallowed to use by Windows Store App). Is there a way to do that for an Universal app (Windows 8.1 or Windows 10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this by setting the `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences`.

e.g.

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```

set it to `.None` if you want to support both.